# ¿Como puedo saber que campos de una tabla son foreign key de otra tabla?

Tags: sql

me explico:

Estoy haciendo una clase para hacer un CRUD desde cualquier tabla dada, y para ello necesito saber mediante query sql cuales campos de una tabla son foreign keys, para poner un desplegable.

Pero ojo no necesito saber que campos de dicha tabla son foreign key en otra sino al revés porque he encontrado mucha info de como hacer eso, es decir que campos en una tabla son foreign key provenientes de otra tabla.

Por ej, en la tabla empleado hay un campo llamado estatus_id, que es la primary key de otra tabla llamada estatus, eso es lo que necesito saber mediante la query y no lo he logrado.

Comment: En qué motor de base de datos?

Comment: Killan, debes indicar el motor de base de datos que estás usando, como ya te indicaron, ya que esto en, es muy particular para cada base de datos.

Comment: Revertí las ediciones porque fueron otros usuarios los que añádieron etiquetas y precisiones que el OP nunca mencionó

Answer (score 2):

Creo que entendí lo que necesitas.
Primero, tienes que escoger la tabla que desees saber sus foreign key de otra tabla (Seleccionas como en la imagen y presionas ALT + F1).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segundo, aparecerá los detalles de la tabla y te vas hasta el ultimo, y te aparecerá esto. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso puedes ver los keys que están en otra tabla. 
Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no me queda muy claro lo que necesitas pero supongamos que tienes una base de datos llamada empleados y las tablas :

```
estatus
(
    id_estatus INT NOT NULL,
    estatus VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_estatus)
) 

empleado
(
    id_empleado INT NOT NULL,
    estatus_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_empleado),
    FOREIGN KEY (estatus_id) REFERENCES estatus(id_estatus)
)
```

Bien si lo que quieres es saber que columnas de empleado contienen llaves foraneas tal vez con un show create table empleado sea suficiente.

pero si lo que quieres es saber dado estatus que tablas usan alguna columna de estatus como llave foranea dependera de que gestor uses te dare un ejemplo de MySQL y quedaria asi:

```
select table_name,COLUMN_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA  = 'empleados'
and referenced_table_name = 'estatus';
```

y daria como resultado:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| table_name | COLUMN_NAME | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| empleado   | estatus_id  | estatus               | id_estatus             |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Pero depende del Gestor ya te tocaria ver en que lugar tu gestor almacena estos datos.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ha presentado algún problema parecido y así lo solucioné:

```
SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'NombreTabla'
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento de la consulta. Lee [answer].