# ¿Como puedo saber que campos son foreign key de una tabla desde una query sql?

Tags: sql, innodb

necesito formular una query para poder averiguar que campos de una tabla X son foreign key de otra para generar otra query sabiendo que campos son y un desplegable HTML más tarde.

Lo que quiero saber exactamente es dada una tabla verificar todos sus campos y saber si alguno es foreign key en esa misma tabla y de que otra tabla proviene, NO AL REVÉS (no necesito saber si ese campo es foreign key en otra tabla sino si ese campo es foreign key en esa misma tabla).

El motor de la base de datos es Inno DB.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias poner un ejemplo de lo que queres? igual suena raro que tengas que averiguar eso, si la db es tuya ya lo deberias saber de antemano

Comment: Parece que es tu misma pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285225/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-saber-que-campos-de-una-tabla-son-foreign-key-de-otra-tabla por que no solo la editas o trata de ser mas especifico.

Comment: Si perdiste acceso a tu vieja cuenta, por favor avisanos, tenemos formas de unir tus perfiles. dejame un comentario con @gbianchi, y uno tus perfiles

Comment: Ok, ya he encontrado exactamente lo que necesitaba, era muy simple: select CONSTRAINT_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME='alumnos'